# How can I get scrollbars when a page is resized?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple web page with a table. I have added the fixed attribute AND the overflow attribute as well but the table always appears "cut off" at the bottom of the page. I am trying to get scrollbars on the page so that when the table rows don't fit (eg. user resizes window), the user should be able to scroll down to the last row.

```
    #dstable {
    table-layout:fixed;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

    #dstable td {
        border: 1px solid white;
        height: 100px;
        width: 300px;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: black;
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    #dstable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: white;
    }

    #dstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #e0f7d0;
    }

    #dstable td:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }

    #dstable th {
        padding: 8px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: more than likely this has underlying issues non related to your table. If you were to put this code in a clean file, it would appear to be fine. You more than likely have other elements encouraging this behavior, or at minimum, other elements in addition too.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `max-height: 90%;` to `#dstable`, that should do the trick.

Comment: What does this do and why? Please provide a better answer. Telling people to do something blindly doesn't teach them of what is going on under the hood. If the height is already set to 90%, what does adding a max-height property value of that same number do?

Comment: I appreciate that, but sometimes things *just work* and the technical reason for it actually working is unknown. This is one such case, or at least I'm not able to provide a technical reason as to why it works. It just works.

Comment: @NikkiMather - Appreciate the response, but the scrollbars are still not appearing. Tried both IE and Chrome.

Comment: @user1554876 are you able to set up a fiddle? It should be a relatively simple fix.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pkamath/xgrsgj01/3/ ---- The strange thing is that when I run this in Fiddle I see the scrollbar (in the lower right hand corner) ... but on my page which has an image, some text AND the table, I don't see the scrollbar.

Comment: I'm not sure on the SO etiquette on this, but feel free to link to the site and I'll take a look.